# Why is $\int H(t,c(t),c^\prime(t)) dt \in \mathcal{C}^r$ if $H \in \mathcal{C}^r$?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

In lecture came up the following remark:

> Consider an interval $I = [t_0,t_1]$ and a finite dimensional Banach space $X$. Let $U$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R} \times X \times X$ and let  $V \subseteq \mathcal{C}^{1}(I,X)$ be the set of all curves $c:I \rightarrow X$, where $(t,c(t),c^\prime(t))$ is contained in $U$ for all $t$. Let further be
>
> $$\lvert\lvert c \rvert\rvert_{\mathcal{C}^1(I)} := \sup_{t \in I} \lvert\lvert c(t) \rvert\rvert_X + \sup_{t \in I}\lvert\lvert c^\prime(t) \rvert\rvert_X.$$
>
> We note that $V$ is open in $\mathcal{C}^1(I,X)$.
> For a $\mathcal{C}^r$ function $H: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ ($r \ge 2$) consider the functional
> $$f: V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, c \mapsto \int H(t,c(t),c^\prime(t)) dt $$
> under side conditions $c(t_0) = x_0$ and $c(t_1) = x_1$. Then $f \in \mathcal{C}^r$.

I do not quite understand why $f \in \mathcal{C}^r$. If $H$ would just be a map from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ this would be clear to me, but this general setting confuses me. Could you please explain this to me?

Answer (score 1):

I think using  [Taylor expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Taylor%27s_theorem_for_multivariate_functions) (expanding the integrand) will prove that $f\in C^{r}$,  Since  $D\in V,\lvert \lvert D-C \rvert \rvert<\delta  \implies  \forall t\in I ,\lvert \lvert D(t)-C(t) \rvert \rvert<\delta \land \lvert \lvert D'(t)-C'(t) \rvert \rvert<\delta$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I can not quite follow you. What do you want to say with $D\in V,\lvert \lvert D-C \rvert \rvert<\delta  \implies \ldots$?